# CSS float issues across several browsers

Tags: css

I have the following CSS setup for use on two different pages;

```
#content{
width:960px;
margin-top:0px; 
height:auto; 
font-family:arial; 
font-size:1.em; 
background-color:#f2f2f2; 
}

#left-div {
width:600px;
padding-top:20px;
text-align:center;
line-height:.5em;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
}

#right-div {
width:300px;
margin-top:40px;
margin-right:20px;
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
float:right;
background-color:#e0e0e0;
}

#isa-left {
width:440px;
margin-top:40px;
margin-left:30px;
margin-right:10px;
display:inline-block;
text-align:justify;
float:left;
}

#isa-right {
width:440px;
margin-top:40px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:30px;
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
float:right;
}
```

On the page where I use left-div and right div like this;

```
<div id="content">
 <div id="left-div"> Content </div>
 <div id="right-div"> Content </div> 
</div>
```

here is what happens. In FF, IE, Safari, and Chrome it looks just I expect with the two divs next to each other with a background color of #f2f2f2 from the `content` div.

On the second page where I use the isa-left and isa-right with the same setup as above what happens is that the inner divs are still showing where I expect them but now the background color from the content div is not showing.

After finding a post on here with the same problem I added this line `overflow:auto;` to the content div.

Now both pages in FF the content appears outside of the content div, 960 pixels to the right, with the background color showing. In IE, Safari, and Chrome both pages appear perfectly.

My question is what is causing the two inner divs to escape the content div in FF once I added `overflow:auto;`? Or is there a way to fix it so that the background color shows through on the second page without using `overflow:auto;`?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Are you just trying to get the divs to stack next to each other? Or are you trying to get them to stick to the outside of your wrapper

Comment: I want them inside wrapper next to each other.

Comment: hang tight, I think I gotcha

Comment: @user3112969 is this not what you want? http://jsbin.com/adELAsEV/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I think it might be the solution to your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/6dBdx/

-Code Reference -

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width:400px;
    margin-top:0px;
    height:auto;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:1.em;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
.wrapper > div.box {
    padding-top:20px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:.5em;
    border:thin solid #999;
    /* Adding this for example purposes */
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
}
.pull-right {
    float:right;
}
.pull-left {
    float:left;
}
.clear-fix {
    clear:both;
}
```

HTML

```
<label>Float Left Only</label>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="pull-left box">One</div>
    <div class="pull-left box">Two</div>
    <div class="clear-fix"></div>
</div>
<label>Float Left &amp; Right</label>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="pull-left box">One</div>
    <div class="pull-right box">Two</div>
    <div class="clear-fix"></div>
</div>
```

Quick notes, don't forget to add a clear div after a float, so that elements show up correctly after floating an element. Also, if you want an element to line up next to each other, try using float:left as a rule of thumb, unless you want the elements to line up on the right in which case... float:right

Comment: I did both float left and added the .wrapper > div.box, and it worked! All 4 browsers too! Thx, I never saw that .wrapper > div.box anywhere before

Comment: Well the > just indicates that you want the CSS Style to only apply to the next level down. Glad it helped though :)